# How to match against Some(&T)?

Tags: rust

The following code won't compile:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    x: i32,
}

pub fn main() {
    let a = vec![Foo { x: 1 }, Foo { x: 2 }];
    match a.get(0) {
        Some(&x) => println!("ref {:?}", x),
        None => {}
    }
}
```

Throws this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:11
  |
8 |     match a.get(0) {
  |           ^^^^^^^^
9 |         Some(&x) => println!("ref {:?}", x),
  |               -
  |               |
  |               data moved here
  |               move occurs because `x` has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I thought `std::Vec<T>::get` returns `Some(&T)` on success. Doesn't that mean an ampersand should be used in pattern matching?

Comment: `&x` on the left side of binding **removes** one layer of reference, so here simply `Some(x)` will work.

Comment: @edwardw I see, apprently i have mixed up pattern matching and reference delaration, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I thought `std::Vec<T>::get` returns `Some(&T)` on success

Yes, you get an `Option` over a reference. Said otherwise, `x`, in `Some(x)` is a reference over the `Foo` instance.

But you *do want* a reference: the only way to print the element without removing it from the vector is to pass a reference to `println`, not the element itself. That's why

```
Some(x) => println!("ref {:?}", x),
```

is the right way.

When you do

```
Some(&x) => println!("ref {:?}", x),
```

on the other way, as `&x` is the reference over the Foo instance, `x` is the `Foo` instance, and thus you'd be moving it out of the vector when matching, which you can't do with a shared reference you got with `get` (and something you certainly don't want to do anyway).